# Joomla Template:: Not able to see newly installed template

Tags: templates, joomla-3.5, administration

I am pretty new to joomla . I have a server http://www.newsnowis.com which was having an old installation and old data. I installed http://demo4.ltheme.com/joomla/lt-news/  template and set this template as default.

Now i open **www.newsnowis.com** what happens is it just redirects to w**ww.newsnowis.com/english/** with a blank screen.

My expectation is it should open the template with sample data. Can anyone sugggest which configuration is wrong and missing? This server is running in godaddy would it be misconfiguration of Cpanel? Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

When I click on your site it looks like it's using the new template but your homepage is set incorrectly.

In the administrator back-end go into your menus and click the gold star to on the menu item that you would like to be your homepage.

For the sample data, looking at the theme creator's site, the sample data is only included in their paid option. Did you purchase the theme? The free version doesn't include it.

See this link and scroll to the pricing and accordions at the bottom "How to make template like demo": https://ltheme.com/project/lt-news-responsive-magazine-news-joomla-template/

[image: theme creators info]